# How do I fix the paths for packed images?

Tags: texturing, blend-files, path

I downloaded a shared .blend file.  I changed a few things and tried to pack the external data .blend file.  It complained about textures and it looks like Blender was looking for the textures on the author's computer?  How do I fix that?  It's not working in the user preferences settings in my Blender.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more information to your question about what  "it looks like Blender was looking for the textures on the author's computer" means? What screen were you seeing? Including screenshots can be helpful to illustrate your question.

Comment: You can try to *Unpack all into files*, make paths relative, then repack

Comment: Hi   I can't put up a screen shot here.  But it essentially says "Report: Error Unable to pack source path"  and it list 4 times a path to images that do not exist on my computer.  I am guessing the paths are on the persons computer that made the.blend file

Comment: Why can't you upload a screenshot here? If Blender searches for the files from another computer you need to get them from another computer.

Comment: I think blickfang means he is working on someone else's file sent or downloaded from the internet or something and Blender is trying to find texture files with absolute paths in their original location from the author computer.

Comment: Duarte that is what I am saying.